# fetching parameters from a jenkins job in java code

Tags: java, jenkins, parameters

I have a parameterised jenkins job that is accessing my plugin. Inside plugin's code in java, i require these parameters using which i have to trigger another job in jenkins. I am not able to fetch these parameters and it is a very high priority issue now. I ahve tried multiple solutions available on stackoverflow, for eg., tried accessing the environment variables but didn't received the param's value. for e.g., my parameter is 'REPOS' and i need its value, i have tried :

```
System.getProperty("REPOS");
```

but it returns null.

Also, tried :

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
              for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
                  System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName, env.get(envName));
              }
```

but it prints the jenkins' environment variables and not the job's parameters.

I am referring to the value passed in the text box beside param: "url" in the below picture.

[image]

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, but it worked when i did the following:
I hit the

```
JENKINS_HOST_URL/job/JENKINS_SEED_JOB_NAME/api/json?pretty=true
```

and found the current build number, thereafter, hitting jenkins again with this number`(JENKINS_HOST_URL/job/JENKINS_SEED_JOB_NAME/currBuildNum/api/json?pretty=true)`,

I was able to fetch all the parameters passed in there in this build.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, Jenkins parameters are exposed as environment variables. However, if you use a build system like Maven that launches Java sub-processes, those variables might not be inherited.

Probably your most reliable approach is to explicitly pass parameters as system properties in your Jenkins configuration, eg `-DREPOS=${REPOS}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response, but only after reading this param can i  launch a new sub - process. Hence, it is required at the first place. Also, can you please explain where n how in jenkins configuration(for this particular job), do i need to provide the command u suggested?

Comment: The config location in Jenkins depends on the nature of your build. If you're using Maven, for example, then the 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' build step includes a 'Properties' text area. Whatever build system you use, there should be some point where you can specify command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

One of the option to achieve this is "PASS and GET AS ARGUMENT" in your java code.

Jenkins's variables value can be retrieved like this.

```
urlValue=${url}
```

Then pass this value in java code. This will be structure of your **Execute shell** in job configuration.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
urlValue=${url} 
# run java code
java <classNameToRun> $urlValue
```

Comment: This is again for passing the value from jenkins, but that i am able to with the use of job. But i want to access them in my java code, that is where i need help.

Comment: In your java code, you should be able to get  the value in your main function. eg, In public static void main (args[]) , you can get value as args[1] , args[2] like that.

Comment: I tried executing it on the jenkins server, but it is asking for a java file. Again i gave the name of my java file used in the plugin development, it gave an error message "Could not find or load main class J.java". Moreover, this parameter will be passed by a post - commit hook from SVN which can pass me only the url param.